# VSCode Flutter Dart lowercase suggestions

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

There is a problem with the suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

[what's happening now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h8FS.png)

[should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOy5v.png)

when written in lowercase letters, it appeared as in image 2

Answer (score 1):

You can always disable the Flutter/Dart extension for Visual Studio Code if it annoys you.

You can also report this issue on the VSC [extension repository](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code)